# Django models in subdirectory

Tags: django

I've set up my Django application like this:

```
root

    modules
        module1
        module2
            models.py
```

Now, when running makemigrations, Django takes the path to a model, which is, without root, modules.module2.Product . This doesn't work. Django tries to create a 2-tuple from this, splitting at '.' in django.db.models.utils. This of course doesn't work because there are three values. How can I tell Django to use module2.Product, which results in table module2_products? I want to use this separation in directories, but I can't get Django to work with me on this. (The model actually already exists in the database in table module2_products, but after some restructuring the code the model is defined a level deeper in the code.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `app_label` in your models' Meta classes.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'module2'
```

Comment: I've tried that indeed, but Django still tries to split the path to get the table name, so it didn't work out like that. I ended up restructuring the directories again to work with Django, instead of working against it..